# Deploying a node.js app to a vps

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean-stack

I've just finished the basics of a node app, based on a stripped down version of the MEAN stack. It's running nicely on my local machine and I'd like to send it live.

I've got a VPS sorted and I think I know the rough principles of how to make it work, but I'm wondering if anyone could explain how updating the app would work?

Is it possible/preferable to be able to test updates to the app on the VPS without the live version being affected, then fold the new parts in once I'm happy with them? Would this mean needing another VPS to do testing on?

If anyone could explain their workflow/methods I would be very appreciative! (In laymans terms!)

Tom.

Comment: Ever use Capistrano? It's popular in Rails community but I found it works well with Node.js apps too: https://github.com/loopj/capistrano-node-deploy. If you don't know Capistrano, read up: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano. It just automates SSH/SCP deploys in Ruby, you can write custom recipes to deploy to staging servers if you wish

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look tonight. Also interested in anything grunt based, as I find that fantastic for front end work.